# Email notifications after 'git archive'?

Tags: git, githooks

Custom requirement: How to notify specific people, using email as soon as a git archive command is run to download a single file?

Couldn't find a hook which can do so.

Comment: Who runs `git archive` command?

Answer (score 0):

> Couldn't find a hook which can do so.

That is because there isn't one associated to the [`git archive`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive) command.

One possible workaround would be to make a global git alias to archive, in order to call a wrapper script which would:

- check who is running that command
- execute the actual `git archive` command
- send an email appropriately

But all that is on the client side, which means this is valid for an environment shared among several clients.

Comment: I assume to check who is running that command, 'git config --list user.email' can be used. Also, can you suggest how can I go about sending email notifications?

Comment: @Siddharth It depends on your OS, but you can take inspiration from https://github.com/git/git/blob/aa25c82427ae70aebf3b8f970f2afd54e9a2a8c6/contrib/hooks/post-receive-email#L757